# INT 21h does not print

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I wonder why this procedure does not print:

```
print:
push ax
push bx
push dx
mov ah, 02h      

ciclo:
mov al, [si]   
int 21h
inc si
loop ciclo

pop dx
pop bx
pop ax 
ret
```

According to [here](http://x86asm.wikia.com/wiki/Int_21h), calling `INT 21h` while `AH` is 2, prints on stdout the ASCII code contained in `AL`. While debugging I found nothing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will print the *character* in `DL` (see [this reference](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2554.htm)).

For example, if `DL` contains the decimal value 65, it will print the character `A` (since 65 is the ASCII code for 'A')